# Clickjacking In Nodejs with Express

Tags: node.js, express, clickjacking

dotenv.config({ path: '.env' });

const app: any = express();

app.disable('x-powered-by');

const helmet = require('helmet')

const originalSend: any = app.response.send;

app.response.send = function sendOverWrite(body: any) {

originalSend.call(this, body)

this.**custombody** = body

}

app.use(helmet())

app.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) =>{

console.log("x-frame")

res.setHeader('X-Frame-Options','DENY');

res.setHeader('Content-Security-Policy', "frame-ancestors 'none'");

next();

});

// cors

app.use(cors());

// Node.js body parsing middleware.

app.use(json());

app.use(urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// views

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../src/views'));

app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// ** LOG handlers

app.use(successHandler);

app.use(errorHandler);

// route

const router = Router;

app.use('/api', router);

// 404

app.get('*', (req: Request, res: Response) => {

res.status(404).send({ message: 'Unauthorized!', status: false });

});

// ? Created one ASYNC function to manage system start after AWS load

(async (port = process.env.APP_PORT || 5000) => {

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`> Listening on port ${port}`));

})();

// ! error handler

app.use((err: any, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {

res.locals.errorMessage = err.message || "System Error";

res.locals.error = process.env.NODE_ENV === Environment.Development ? err.stack || err : {};

res.status(err.status || 500);

res.send("System Error, Please contact tech support!");

});

In this Server.ts file wanted enable header options 'Content-Security-Policy', "frame-ancestors 'none'" and 'X-Frame-Options','DENY' to avoid clickjacking.

below provided code, where I am checking Clickjacking

Clickjacking PoC